# Prove : A finite subset of $\Bbb N$ has one maximum

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Prove : A finite non-empty subset $S\subseteq \Bbb N$ has one maximum

Compare with that: a finite subset of $\Bbb N$ has one least number.

Comment: $N$ is the set of natural numbers, right?

Comment: Slight modification: finite non-empty subset.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Hi, Do you think notation $N$ is enough to denote  natural numbers in SE?

Comment: @HyperGroups: you can call it what you like as long as you specify what you mean, but I prefer $\Bbb N$, or, in appropriate contexts, $\omega$.

Comment: @HyperGroups: Well, the blackboard bold of the edit is standard. Actually, even that has some ambiguity since some people include $0$ and others don't. Not that it matters for this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Let $S_n=\{s_1,\ldots,s_n\}$ be a finite non-empty subset of natural numbers with finite cardinality $n$. We proceed by induction on $n$.

**Base Case:** For $n=1$, the claim vacuously holds true.

**Induction Step:** Assume that the claim holds true for $n=k$.

It remains to prove the claim true for $n=k+1$. Consider the set $S_{k+1}=\{s_1,\ldots,s_k,s_{k+1}\}$. By the induction hypothesis, we know that $S_k=\{s_1,\ldots,s_k\}$ has a maximum element so that for some $i\in\{1,...,k\}$, we have $s_i > s_j$ for all $j\in\{1,...,k\}\setminus\{i\}$. Note that since sets cannot have repeated elements, we know that $s_i \neq s_{k+1}$. Hence, there are two cases to consider:

**Case 1:** Suppose $s_i > s_{k+1}$. Then since $s_i > s_j$ for all $j\in\{1,...,k+1\}\setminus\{i\}$, we know that $s_{i}$ is the unique maximum element of $S_{k+1}$, as desired.

**Case 2:** Suppose $s_{k+1} > s_i$. Then since $s_i > s_j$ for all $j\in\{1,...,k\}\setminus\{i\}$, we know by the transitivity of $>$ that $s_{k+1}> s_j$ for all $j\in\{1,...,k\}$, so $s_{k+1}$ is the unique maximum element of $S_{k+1}$, as desired.